# Expectation maximum between a constant and a random variable

Tags: random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable. For sake of simplicity assume it is uniformly distributed from $[0,1]$. Let $c$ be a constant in the same interval.

How do I express $E[\max(X,c)]$ in such a case?

Comment: You can call $Y=\max(X,c)$ your new random variable. It takes values in $[c,1]$ and you have $P(Y=c)=c$ and $P(Y>c)=1-c$.

Comment: Hi: welcome to the internet! Typing in all caps has been considered bad etiquette since before the turn of the last century. Perhaps you'd like to switch it to a nice title case or even lower case in the future. (Asaf did you a favor and switched it for you. Thanks Asaf!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{E}[\max(X,c)] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid X > c]\Pr[X > c] + \operatorname{E}[c \mid X \le c]\Pr[X \le c] = \frac{c+1}{2} \cdot (1-c) + c \cdot c.$$  The first equality is applicable for any distribution on $X$.  The second applies specifically to the case where $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ with $c \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $Y=\max(X,c)$. If $X\lt c$ then $Y=c$. Note that $\Pr(Y=c)=c$.

If $X\ge c$ then, by symmetry, $Y$ has expectation $\frac{1+c}{2}$.

Comment: Depends on $c$. If $c=0.05$ then the probability that $Y=c$ is small. So the expectations I mentioned have to be weighted appropriately.

Comment: I just understood the way you wrote it, sorry. That's kind of big hint though. I'll delete my comment :)

Comment: The not mentioning the weights made it a hint and not a solution.