# Expectation of maximum between zero and a function of a random variable

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $v$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over [0,1]. Let $\alpha$ be a constant, where $0<\alpha<1/2$, so that $0<2\alpha<1$.

**How can I express: $\mathbb{E}\left(Max\{2\alpha, v\}-v\right)$?**

---

Here's what I've tried "intuitively":

1. $$\mathbb{E}(Max\{2\alpha, v\}-v) = \mathbb{E}(Max\{2\alpha-v, 0\})\\
   =\mathbb{P}(2\alpha-v \geq 0)\cdot (2\alpha-v)+ [1-\mathbb{P}(2\alpha-v \geq 0)]\cdot 0 \\
   = \mathbb{P}(v \leq 2\alpha) \cdot (2\alpha-v) + 0 = 2\alpha \cdot (2\alpha-v)$$
2. Which seems incorrect given [this very similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027796/expectation-maximum-between-a-constant-and-a-random-variable). Instead,

$$\mathbb{E}(Max\{2\alpha, v\}-v) = \mathbb{E}(Max\{2\alpha-v, 0\})\\
=\mathbb{P}(2\alpha-v \geq 0)\cdot \mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v\geq0)+ [1-\mathbb{P}(2\alpha-v \geq 0)]\cdot 0 \\
= \mathbb{P}(2\alpha-v \geq 0)\cdot \mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v\geq 0) \\
= \mathbb{P}(v \leq 2\alpha) \cdot \mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v\geq 0)\\
= 2\alpha \cdot \mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v\geq 0)$$

However I am not sure about $\mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v>0)$, in turn because I can't find the distribution of $2\alpha-v$, is it a Uniform over [-1, 1]? so that we would have: $\mathbb{E}(2\alpha-v|2\alpha-v> 0)=1/2$, and $\mathbb{E}\left(Max\{2\alpha, v\}-v\right) = \alpha$?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot have the answer in terms of $v$ (which is a r.v.. So your attempt fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that your "intuitive" method (1) is not correct - notice that your random variable $v$ still appears at the end of your expected value, which should be a number.

Your method (2) following the linked post uses a wise strategy (the "law of total expectation" to decompose it into two manageable parts). Your calculations up to the end look correct, so it suffices to compute $\mathbb{E}[2\alpha - v \mid 2\alpha - v > 0]$ as you recognised.

Notice that $v \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0, 1)$, so $2\alpha - v \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(2\alpha, 2\alpha - 1)$. You can prove that $2 \alpha - v \mid 2\alpha - v > 0$ is actually uniform over $[0, 2\alpha]$ - intuitively this is by symmetry, and more rigorously you can prove this by using the definition of conditional probability. Thus, the expected value is $\alpha$.

(Alternatively, the answer by @Kavi Rama Murthy is of course true in general as well, since it is essentially using the definition of expectation.)

Comment: Thank you! All good :)

Answer (score 1):

Distribution of $2\alpha -v$ is not needed. Use the fact that if $X$ has density function $f$ then $Eg(X)=\int g(x)f(x)dx$

$E(2\alpha -v|2\alpha -v \geq 0)=\frac 1 {2\alpha} \int_0^{2\alpha} (2\alpha -t)dt=\alpha$.

[The denominator is $P(v \leq 2\alpha)$].

Comment: Thank you! Is $\mathbb{E}(2\alpha -v | 2\alpha -v \geq 0)$ equal to $\mathbb{E}(2\alpha -v | v \leq 2 \alpha)$ ?
If no, maybe I've done a mistake earlier and not formulate my question correctly... (sorry about that). What would be $\mathbb{E}(2\alpha -v | v \leq 2\alpha)$ equal to then?

Comment: First question: YES. Second question: You have to evaluate it using the density function. That is what I have done in my answer.  @Banalaude

Comment: All good now, thanks again!